# flex:1 makes my view disapear in react-native

Tags: react-native

i am new to react i m trying to make the background color of my main container cover all the screen but when i use flex 1 everything seems to disappear i've  seen many people doing it and it turned fine i can't understand the problem since i m using it on my container .

```js
import React from 'react';
import mainstyles from '../styles/mainstyles';
import {
    Button,
    Text,
    View,
    AlertButton,
    TouchableOpacity,
  } from 'react-native';

 const UploadFile = ()=>{
     return (
        <View style={mainstyles.container}>
            <Text style={mainstyles.title}>Ocr Scan</Text>
            <Text style={mainstyles.par}>Import a file and start digitizing</Text>
            <Button 
            title="Take picture"
            />
            <Button 
            title="Upload file"
            />
        
        </View>
        
     );
 };

  export default UploadFile;
```

```js
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

const mainstyles=StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
      
   },
```

Comment: add this to container style:
`width: '100%',
height: '100%'`

Comment: i added it and had to delete the flex for it to work, so thank you a lot ..however, do you know why the flex didn't work still, I've seen people using it in tutorials on their containers and they didn't run to problems

Comment: i can't find any error in your code, add more code for clarification

Comment: @Rihabsabri it can't be decided with just a chunk of code, there must be some small mistake like the view where you are rendering this component doesn't have any style? or anyother error. However, it can only be decided after watching the whole working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use flex on a component A, every component B that nest component A need to use flex.

Comment: You just saved me so much time thank you.

Answer (score 1):

adding `height:'100%'` on parent element solved the problem for me.

Give `height:'100%'` to the view where you are rendering this component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).